Switching Between IPsec and IKEv2 Protocols - Connection Invalid
I have a setup with IPsec and IKEv2 protocol options. When I disconnect one protocol and attempt to connect with the other, I encounter the error: "Failed to fetch info with type 2: Connection invalid." Following this, I also receive an alert stating, "Negotiation with the VPN server failed." All configurations appear correct.
I am confident about the correctness of the passwordReference and sharedSecretReference
values and I have been verifying them.
When I check the logs with sample outputs, there is no changing information except for the key references and protocol type. However, after closing and reopening the application, if the user attempts to reconnect to the previously failed protocol, the connection succeeds.
Here's the log output for reference:
print ("protocolConfiguration : ", self. vpnManager.protocolConfiguration ?? "nil data")
I've been trying to find a solution for a while now, does anyone have a solution or any ideas?
